# What Peoplecode syntax is required to pass an enum constant to a class method of a java object using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, enums, peoplecode

I am using the Apache POI class [SXSSFWorkbook](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/SXSSFWorkbook.html) through Peoplecode to write large amounts of data to an excel file.  I know very little Java but was able to put together code which produces the file using java reflection through Peoplecode.  Unfortunately there is a bug in Peoplecode which makes it necessary to use reflection even when a method is not overloaded.

As an example, to execute the following java code:

```
SXSSFWorkbook workbook = new SXSSFWorkbook(100); /* 100 rows of accessible data */
SXSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheet(&name);
```

The equivalent in Peoplecode using java reflection is:

```
   &_workbook = CreateJavaObject("org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook", 100);
   &_sheet = GetJavaClass("org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFSheet");

   Local JavaObject &javaString = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.String", &name);
   Local JavaObject &stringType = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Class[]", &javaString.getClass());
   Local JavaObject &getSheet = &_class.getDeclaredMethod("getSheet", &stringType);
   Local JavaObject &args = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Object[]", &javaString);
   &_sheet = &getSheet.invoke(&_workbook, &args);
```

This technique works for all the methods using String, Integer, boolean as a parameter value.

Now I need to disable the Zip64 extensions by using the enum constant "Never".

Required java code:
`workbook.setZip64Mode(Zip64Mode.Never);`

Updated:
I tried the following

```
   &_workbook = CreateJavaObject("org.apache.poi.xssf.streaming.SXSSFWorkbook");

   &_class = &_workbook.getClass();
      Local JavaObject &javaString = GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode").valueOf("Never");   
   Local JavaObject &stringType = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Class[]", GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode"));
   Local JavaObject &setZip64Mode = &_class.getDeclaredMethod("setZip64Mode", &stringType);
   Local JavaObject &args = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Object[]", &javaString);
   
   &setZip64Mode.invoke(&_workbook, &args);
   &_class = Null;
```

This executes but does not change the size of the output file at all.
GetJavaClass(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode).valueOf("Never"); returns a string value of "org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode" instead of "Never".

[setZip64Mode(org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode zip64Mode)](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/Zip64Mode.html)

What am I missing?

Comment: `Never` is a `static` field of the class `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode`. Alternatively, you can call the `static` method [`valueOf`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-compress/apidocs/org/apache/commons/compress/archivers/zip/Zip64Mode.html#valueOf(java.lang.String)) on that class passing the string `"Never"`. You already linked to the class, so why did you even think that you can pass a string where an instance of `org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode` is expected?

Comment: I was just illustrating the code I was using to try to solve the problem.  Thanks for the suggestion, however GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode").valueOf("Never"); only returns the class name and not the string.

Comment: I don’t know what peoplecode’s `valueOf` method does. I thought, you’d call Java’s `valueOf` method using `getDeclaredMethod`/`invoke` like you invoked the `getSheet` method and the `setZip64Mode` method.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research and additional information the code below is working as expected.

```
   &_class = &_workbook.getClass();
   Local JavaObject &javaString = GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode").valueOf("Never");   
   Local JavaObject &stringType = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Class[]", GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode"));
   Local JavaObject &setZip64Mode = &_class.getDeclaredMethod("setZip64Mode", &stringType);
   Local JavaObject &args = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.Object[]", &javaString);
   
   &setZip64Mode.invoke(&_workbook, &args);
   &_class = Null;
```

However, it was discovered that Peoplecode gives the same error if a java method does not exist OR if it was not called with the correct syntax (parameter type)

The code below can be used instead of the reflection code shown above:

```
Local JavaObject &enumValue = CreateJavaObject("java.lang.String", "Never");
&_workbook.setZip64Mode(GetJavaClass("org.apache.commons.compress.archivers.zip.Zip64Mode").valueOf(&enumValue));
```

Although the file size did not change, it was observed to not produce a zip-bomb error when opened for reading.  This was the actual problem.  To check whether the file could successfully be processed, Araxis-Merge was used to validate the file.

[Example of Zip-Bomb error and valid file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a7pVK.png)